# Pygobject build fails

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to install Pygobject on my 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 by following instructions given here: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

It recommends using `jhbuild` to build pygobject. So I install `jhbuild` (something I've never seen before following instructions given here: https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/getting-started.html.en) which worked out fine.

Initially I had to run `jhbuild sysdeps --install` to install missing dependencies which took a LONG time. After it was done it said `Nothing to install` which I presume means it found everything it needed.

Then the
`jhbuild bootstrap` command said `*** success *** [1/1]`. OK.

The `jhbuild sanitycheck` gives no output, (supposedly) meaning all is well.

Then, I run the command `jhbuild build pygobject` and get error:

```
Checking if "C_IN in public headers (no arpa/nameser_compat.h needed)" 
compiles: NO
Checking if "arpa/nameser_compat.h needed for C_IN" compiles: NO

gio/meson.build:35:6: ERROR:  Problem encountered: Could not find 
required includes for ARPA C_IN

A full log can be found at 
/home/anshulvj/.cache/jhbuild/build/glib/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
*** Error during phase configure of glib: ########## Error running 
meson --prefix /home/anshulvj/jhbuild/install --libdir lib - 
Dlibmount=false --buildtype=debugoptimized -Dgtk_doc=false 
/home/anshulvj/jhbuild/checkout/glib *** [6/10]

[1] Rerun phase configure
[2] Ignore error and continue to build
[3] Give up on module
[4] Start shell
[5] Reload configuration
[6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"
choice:
```

Doesn't matter what I choose, it either ends the build or gives errors like the following, if I choose [2]:

```
*** Building glib *** [6/10]
ninja  
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
*** Error during phase build of glib: ########## Error running ninja   
*** [6/10]
.
.
.
```

and then

```
 configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.57.1) were not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.57.1' but version of GLib is 2.48.2

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GLIB_CFLAGS
and GLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
*** Error during phase configure of gobject-introspection: ########## Error running /home/anshulvj/jhbuild/checkout/gobject-introspection/autogen.sh --prefix /home/anshulvj/jhbuild/install --disable-Werror --with-python=python3 --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc  *** [9/10]
```

Which is weird because I cannot find anything related to installing `glib2.57` or greater online. (https://github.com/GNOME/glib)

The documentation at https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html does not deal with these errors and I'm completely lost. I googled a lot but did not find anyone who was facing the same issue. If this does not work I'm going to give up on Python3+GTK3+.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

EDIT: Today I tried installing based on instructions given here https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html using pip. It doesn't matter if I use pip or pip3 I get the following error.

```
(venv) anshulvj@anshulvj-HP-ZBook-15-G3:~/IRS2-415-Python$ pip3 install pygobject
Collecting pygobject
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/e8/1e4f21800015a9ca153969e85fc29f7962f8f82fc5dbc1ecbdeb9dc54c75/PyGObject-3.28.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.11.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pygobject) (1.17.1)
Installing collected packages: pygobject
  Running setup.py install for pygobject ... error
    Complete output from command /home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-6r4kbumk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/include/site/python3.6/pygobject:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/repository
    copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/repository
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    running build_ext
    pycairo: new API
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py", line 840, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py", line 835, in main
        zip_safe=False,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py", line 684, in run
        self._setup_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py", line 680, in _setup_extensions
        add_pycairo(gi_cairo_ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py", line 665, in add_pycairo
        ext.include_dirs += [get_pycairo_include_dir()]
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py", line 582, in get_pycairo_include_dir
        include_dir = find_path(find_new_api())
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py", line 532, in find_new_api
        import cairo
      File "/home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
    ImportError: /home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-6r4kbumk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/include/site/python3.6/pygobject" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-kikh0jeu/pygobject/
```

Could not find much about

```
ImportError: /home/anshulvj/IRS2-415-Python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index
```

online. Any help is appreciated.